# Using the Well ordering Principal to prove a property of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Use the Well ordering Principle for the integers to prove that given any integer $n>0$ there exists an integer $m$ and a non negative integer $k$ such that $n=3^{k}.m$ and $3$ is not a divisor of $m$

What i tried

The Well ordering principle states that

A least element exists in every non empty set of positive integers

My own  version of the proof

Let the set $S$ be the set that represent represent the negation of the statement, $n=3^{k}m$

Hence the set $S$ is non empty and by the Wop the exists a least element $n=b$

Let $b=1$

Hence $1=3^{k}.m$

Which gives $3^{0}=3^{k}.m$

hence $b>1$

$P(b)$ is untrue

Then since $b$ is the least element, then $P(b-1)$ lies outside the set $S$ and have to be true

Hence this gives

$b-1=3^{k}.m$

From the original equation

$b=3^{k}.m$

Combining both  eqn, we get

$3^{k}.m-1=3^{k}.m$

Hence $1=0$ which is a contradiation

Hence proving the original statement

Is this way of proving also correct. Could any explain.Thanks

Comment: The argument contains the germs of the idea, but is incomplete. You really want to work with the complement of $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a positive integer $n$ **bad** if it cannot be represented as $3^k m$, where $k$ is a non-negative integer and $m$ is not divisible by $3$.

We want to show there are no bad positive integers. Suppose to the contrary that the set $B$ of bad integers is non-empty. Then $B$ contains a least element $b$.

Note that $b$ must be divisible by $3$. For suppose to the contrary it is not. then $b=3^0 b$. Since $b$ is not divisible by $3$, it follows that $b$ cannot be bad.

So $3$ divides $b$. Let $b=3b'$. By the minimality of $b$, the number $b'$ must be good. So there is a $k\ge 0$ and an $m$ such that $3$ does not divide $m$ and $b'=3^k m$. But then $b=3^{k+1}m$, contradicting the fact that $b$ is bad.

Comment: I have modified my question above to include my own slightly different version of the proof. Is that correct. Thanks

Comment: I will look at it and comment, but not immediately.

Comment: There are problems of phrasing,  But the most serious problem is from "$P(b)$ is untrue" to the end. It is true that $b-1$ is by definition "good." But you **cannot** derive a contradiction from that. In particular, the $k$ and $m$ for $b-1$ need not be the same, in fact cannot be the same as for $b$, so you did not correctly derive a contradiction. Basically we need to work with $b/3$, as in the answer above, and **not** $b-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your set $S$ is not well-defined.  DO you mean for $S$ to be all of $\mathbb{N}$?

Instead, fix integer $n$, and let $$S=\{m:\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0},n=3^km\}$$

Comment: Yup that should be the proper way of writing the set.

Answer (score 1):

Take the least integer $n$, which is not of the desired form. Note that $n>1$, since $1=3^0 \cdot 1$. So $n$ has a prime factor $p$. Consider $\frac{n}{p}$ and distinguish between $p=3$ or $p \neq 3$.